# Unable to use Tensorflow Keras in scala

Tags: scala, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use **Tensorflow and Keras** in **scala** - for this I've added library dependencies of Tensorflow which works **fine** for me. I've followed [official tensorflow github](https://github.com/tensorflow/java/#tensorflow-version-support) to use tensorflow in scala.

Also I want to add **Keras** in scala - in order to use its pre-trained models to get face embeddings and compare those embeddings. But I'm unable to use Keras in scala.

I've found a github project which depicts how can we use Keras in scala - I've followed that with same versions of **Scala (2.13.1)** and **Sbt (1.3.2)** which they used in Github Project. I've followed [this](https://github.com/dhruvrajan/tensorflow-keras-scala).

Here is my **build.sbt**:

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.1"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "tensorflow-keras-test"
    resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.15" % Test,
      "org.tensorflow" % "libtensorflow_jni" % "1.15.0",
      "org.tensorflow" % "tensorflow-keras" % "0.0.1"
    )
  )
```

But it is giving **Build Structure Failed**.

**Guide me how can I use Keras in scala - and use some pre-trained model to get and compare face embeddings?**